# R shiny and rscript.exe

Tags: r

I have tried to make use of a .bat in windows to open and run an r shiny app.

It all works and I even get the listening prompt displayed.

However, no web interface opens.

Has anyone else met this problem and resolved it?

Comment: What exactly do you see as output? Are you expecting a browser window to automatically open for you? That's unlikely to happen running non-interactively via Rscript. It should give you a url that you can manually open in your browser yourself.

Comment: Yeah that’s the route I had to go down in the end